# Drools - frequent exceptions in StatelessKnowledgeSession

Tags: java, drools

We are using the Drools Rules Engine with Jboss EAP 6.2. When running under load (only maybe 4-5 new sets of facts being inserted) we frequently see the following stacktrace: If the same data is reinserted then generally no error occurs

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.drools.core.impl.StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.execute(StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:344)
[drools-core-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.kie.camel.component.KieExecuteProducer.process(KieExecuteProducer.java:96)
[kie-camel-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:60)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.kie.camel.component.KiePolicy$KieProcess.process(KiePolicy.java:330)
[kie-camel-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.syncInvoke(CxfRsInvoker.java:130)
[camel-cxf-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.performInvocation(CxfRsInvoker.java:60)
[camel-cxf-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
[cxf-api-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
[cxf-api-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
[cxf-api-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
[cxf-api-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
[cxf-api-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
[jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
[cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
[jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
[jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Do you know anything about Drools? If not: please don't downvote or vote for closing. First step is to look at the dump and *then* ask for relevant parts.

Comment: @laune I don't, so I just left that comment and didn't downvote. If it's not a relevant comment then apologies to the OP!

Comment: @Conleth Are you executing multiple requests against the same session? How is the server handling a request?

Comment: @laune - We are executing against multiple requests against the same session. We are using Restful Requests to send the data in XML format. We are using Apache Camel to do the routing between JBoss and the Rules Engine. My feeling has been that this is not a coding issue but a setup issue. The stacktrace is always the same, so was hoping someone knew the Drools code at the point at which the exception is occurring.

Comment: Hmm, yes: this smells like a race condition: you need a single stateless session for each request as there is a dispose call at the end. - I don't know whether you could use a stateful session, if so, try that. - There shouldn't be an undiagnosed NPE deep in some *Impl.java, so chances are, it's a bug. Trying 6.2.0 Final is another thing worth trying. If the same happens there (in another source code line?) reporting a bug would be advisable. I don't know of another workaround - the layers of code in the server hide very well what's really going on at Drools level.